# Carrierwave + Fog + S3 remove file without going through a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am building an application that has a chat component to it.  The application allows users to upload files to the chat.  The chat is all javascript but i wanted to use Carrierwave for the uploads because i am using it elsewhere in the application.  I am doing the handling of the uploads through AJAX so that i can get into Rails land and let Carrierwave take over.

I have been able to get the chat to successfully upload the files to the correct location in my S3 bucket.  The thing i can't figure out is how to delete the files.  Here is my code the uploads the files - this is the method that is called from the route that the AJAX call hits.

```
def upload
  file = File.open(params[:file_0].tempfile)
  uploader = ChatUploader.new
  uploader.store!(file)
end
```

There is little to no documentation with Carrierwave on how to upload files without going through a model and basically NO documentation on how to remove files without going through a model.  I assume it is possible though - i just need to know what to call.  So i guess my question is how do i delete files?

**UPDATE (11/23)**

I got the code to save and delete files from S3 using these methods:

```
# code to save the file
def upload
    file = File.open(params[:file_0].tempfile)
    uploader = ChatUploader.new
    uploader.store!(file)
    uploader.store_path()
end

# code to remove files
def remove_file
    file = params[:file]
    uploader = ChatUploader.new
    uploader.retrieve_from_store!(file)
    uploader.remove!
end
```

My only issue now is that the filename for the uploaded file is not correct.  It saves all files with a "RackMultipart" and then some numbers which look like a date, time, and identifier? (example: RackMultipart20141123-17740-1tq4j1g)  Need to try and use the original filename plus maybe a timestamp for uniqueness.

I believe it has something to do with these two lines:

```
file = File.open(params[:file_0].tempfile)
```

and

```
uploader.store!(file)
```

Comment: You could use fog directly to circumvent the model requirement, but I guess I'm not clear on why you want to do that. If you don't use models then it makes it a bit harder to keep track of what files you do and don't have available (or at least I perceive that to be a lot of the value of something like carrierwave). Could you explain why you desire that a bit? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, no problem. I am using Carrierwave with models elsewhere im my application.  I was just trying to use what i already had implemented rather than use something else.  My chat is not using the database that the rest of the application is using - i'm using Firebase to store the chat data.  Because of that, there are no models related to the chat.  Does that make sense?  I did finally get it working, it now saves and deletes files from S3.  I'll update the code to show how i got it working.

Comment: I am still having a problem with the filenames though, i added a comment above explaining the issue.

Comment: Looks like carrierwave checks the filename method on uploader, which looks like it must default to the actual filename. So you could override the filename method within you uploader class potentially. Beyond that I'm afraid I'm uncertain as I don't really know the carrierwave side of the equation very well.

Comment: Don't use the tempfile may be you can use the original file name. Else you have to keep track of the actual file name.